# TestNG - emailable-report issue

Tags: email, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have created java method to send mail and that mail attaching TestNG emailable-report. Mail and report is sending fine to specified email address.

My issue is I am calling sendmail method at last means when all other tests complete but thing is I am always getting previous last report in mail. So is it like TestNG update report after all class execution?

I want to get latest emailable-report in mail rather than previous last emailable-report.. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to get latest emailable-report in mail rather than previous
>   last emailable-report.. How can I do that?

I think..you're sending mail in your `@aftersuite`.You're getting previous test emailable-report because the test is currently running and only when it finishes reports will be generated.

I will suggest you to use a continuous Integration server like jenkins because it gives sending emails as a post build option or build tool like Maven or ant to run your tests, then have a post test event to email the results.Maven also provides many plugins to automatically send mails after test execution like Postman mail plugin

**Another solution** : If you are not willing to use a continuous Integration server(jenkins) or maven or ant

**TestNG IReporter listener**

Create your own CustomReport by implementing your class to `IReporter` Interface.This interface has only one method to implement generateReport. This method has all the information of a complete test execution in the List and we can generate report using it.

```
public class CustomReporter implements IReporter{

        @Override

        public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> arg0, List<ISuite> arg1,

                String outputDirectory) {

            // Second parameter of this method ISuite will contain all the suite executed.

            for (ISuite iSuite : arg1) {

             //Get a map of result of a single suite at a time

                Map<String,ISuiteResult> results =    iSuite.getResults();

             //Get the key of the result map

                Set<String> keys = results.keySet();

            //Go to each map value one by one

                for (String key : keys) {

                 //The Context object of current result

                ITestContext context = results.get(key).getTestContext();

            //results of all the test case will be stored in the context object

            //Ex: context.getFailedTests(); will give all failed tests and similarly you can get passed and skipped test results make your own html report using the above data 
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

Hope this helps you...Kindly get back if you need any further help

Comment: So if I use TestNG IReporter listener means I can not use that emailable report and will need to create custom report , right?

Comment: @Helping Hands Yes you need to create a CustomReporter class like the one above

Comment: Happy to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows OS, I've created (for TestNG) in @AfterSuite at the end a method to send mail with attachment and batch file with 2 steps. First step launch **mvn clean test** to execute all test without previous results. Second step launch test **without parameter clean** and operates on non existing group :)
Batch is in folder with tests.

```
start /wait cmd /k "mvn clean test && exit"  /secondary /minimized
REM to send email with results in file, whitch was composed after test suite (mvn without: clean)
start /wait cmd /k "mvn test -Dgroups=PhantomGroupNonExist && exit" /secondary /minimized
```